# javascript table tag crush the jquery next function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a js code to preview image of each input file after I insert image my problem is if I don't use input and image inside table it's work but if I use input and image inside table will not work

my HTML code is

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="file" class="img-control" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <img class="img-preview" src="#" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<br><br>

<input type="file" class="img-control" />
<img class="img-preview" src="#" />
<br><br>

<input type="file" class="img-control" />
<img class="img-preview" src="#" />
<br><br>
```

and my JS code is

```
<script type=text/javascript>
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

function readURL() {
    var $input = jQuery(this);
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            $input.next('.img-preview').attr('src', e.target.result).show();
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    }
}

jQuery(".img-control").change(readURL);
});
</script>
```

The code outside table tag both input are working but the input inside table isn't working and I want to create my inputs inside table each input inside a table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `next()` only looks for next ***sibling*** and the `<input>` has no siblings inside the `<td>`

Try changing:

```
$input.next('.img-preview').attr('src', e.target.result).show();
```

To

```
$input.closest('tr').find('.img-preview').attr('src', e.target.result).show();
// OR
$input.parent().next().find('.img-preview').attr('src', e.target.result).show();
```

Comment: `To` will not work with other `input type="file"` outside the table.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping OP stated they wanted all this inside a table instead of outside